# Blocking external access to directory but allowing SSI access (or, How does the `FilesMatch` directive actually work?)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssi

On an old site, where i was using PHP, I had a `.htaccess` in directory `/noaccess` as follows:

```
# /noaccess/.htaccess
<FilesMatch "^.*$">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

And I had a PHP file like,

```
<html>
<body>
<?php include('noaccess/blah.ssi'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine and the contents of `blah.ssi` is visible.

However, on my current site I'm using SSI and the following:

```
<html>
<body>
<!--#include virtual="noaccess/blah.ssi" -->
</body>
</html>
```

does not work. The logs show `unable to include "noaccess/blah.ssi"`. Remove the `FilesMatch` directive and it works. So I'm obviously misunderstanding how that command works, I didn't realise it would block Apache itself. So how can I block access from the web but allow SSI access? (I thought I could (and should) store the stuff I don't want accessed outside of `public_html` but that doesn't seem to work either in the SSI include - but anyway, even if it did, I'm interested to know how to do this).

Thanks, T.

Comment: why don't you move those file outside of the root directory of your website...

Comment: Hi, thanks, but as I mentioned in my post I have thought of that and if it's possible will do that but I'm having problems getting it to work that way.

Comment: @RageZ. To be clear on the previous PHP project I couldn't do that because the webhost didn't allow you to drop out of the root directory. The current one thankfully I can, but the SSI includes don't seem to let me! Anything preceded with a `/` is deemed at the root level of the site so `/home/...` won't work, and `../../noaccess` doesnt seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know by experience, mod_include follows the limits of the client, so you cannot do what you want with apache directives.

If you want to hide the included files you can disable directory indexes with the `Options -Indexes` directive on your `.htaccess` file, though. Also, you can name the included files in a hard to guess way.

My prefered option would be using uuids, you can generate them with [online tools](http://www.uuidgenerator.com/) or install some utility on your workstation:

```
itorres@localhost$ uuid
6e8feb48-1a3b-11e0-a0e3-00505624a126
itorres@localhost$ vi noaccess/6e8feb48-1a3b-11e0-a0e3-00505624a126.ssi
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only wanted to not allow people to see your files if they enter it in an address bar, then you could put them in a directory with no indexes (`-Indexes`) and an unpublished name and if you never reveal the names of the files (which SSI does not do), then you only need worry if someone guesses one correctly. You can always block access by disallowing according to referrer, or something similar.