# Is it possible to Server Side Include something above webroot?

Tags: apache, ssi

A follow up to my [(flop of a) question(!), here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4467030/380621). As said in the post there and *hopefully* clarified a bit in the comments; I'm having trouble getting a `virtual SSI #include` to look above the root directory of my site. Absolute paths just look from the root directory, and with relative paths starting `../` I get `Invalid URI in request` in the logs. So I'm thinking it's not possible, but partly thinking maybe my server setup is just missing something somewhere. Should I be looking to move to another way to include (PHP?), I'd prefer not but I've got to get this working. I'm sure there must be some information on this out there but for all my searching I've found nothing helpful. Maybe my google skills are not up to scratch.

Oh, and the server is Apache 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSI `virtual` directive works based on URL, not on files, as you can see in the [Apache Tutorial: Introduction to Server Side Includes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/ssi.html#additionalexamples) (emphasis is mine):

> The `virtual` attribute is probably more useful, and should **specify a URL relative** to the document being served. It can start with a /, but must be on the same server as the file being served

If you delve further on [SSI include element](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_include.html#element.include) reference documentation you find it clearly stated:

> **virtual**
>   The value is a (%-encoded) URL-path. The URL cannot contain a scheme or hostname, only a path and an optional query string. If it does not begin with a slash (/) then it is taken to be relative to the current document.

The `file` command cannot contain ../ so if you were thinking on following that alternative road, don't.

> **file**
>   The value is a path relative to the directory containing the current document being parsed. It cannot contain ../, nor can it be an absolute path. Therefore, you cannot include files that are outside of the document root, or above the current document in the directory structure. The virtual attribute should always be used in preference to this one.

Hope that helps.