# Disallow to open and crawl HTML files

Tags: html, seo, search-engine, bots, web-crawler

I have HTML-files in root and also in separate directory that are included via SSI into other pages.

1. How to disallow opening this HTML-files by direct URLs but still leave them accessible for SSI in same moment? .htaccess or something else? Is it possible in general?
2. How to disallow crawling this HTML-files for search engine bots? If I have them included in SSI on other pages but don't have any direct links to them on site will search engine bots see them?

Comment: Not quite sure about the SSI access, but you can use [robots.txt](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1061943) to indicate that you don't want certain files/directories indexed.

Comment: Good, what about real people if someone type direct address to HTML-file that included by SSI?

Comment: There has been [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467030/blocking-external-access-to-directory-but-allowing-ssi-access-or-how-does-the) before. It seems like you can't do what you want - there's one 'alternative' there although I don't particularly like it.

Comment: @norfavrell do know how to do what write? _If you want to hide the included files you can disable directory indexes with the Options -Indexes directive on your .htaccess file, though._

Comment: `Options -Indexes` will only cause Apache not to generate it's [directory index](http://www.windracer.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/wr_before_indices-732875.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a robots.txt and add the following:

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /foldername-you-want-to-disallow/ # hides all files in this directory from bots
Disallow: /hidden.html # hides a specific file in the root dir from bots
Disallow: /foldername/hidden.html # hides a specific file in a subdir from bots
```

OR

You could create an .htaccess file and upload it into the directory you want to hide. Include
the following:

```
Options -Indexes

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

You will still be able to call them via SSI but any http direct requests will be foiled.

Comment: Thank you, Cynthia, what about real people if they type direct address to HTML-file that I use to include through SSI? Does it help in this situation too? If want also disallow from robots a few other HTML-page from root what should I use? Is there something like `User-agent: * Disallow: /folder/ Disallow: /page1.html Disallow: /page2.html`? If I don't have links to that pages and folders that I want disallow do bots will see or find them?

Comment: @user1586029: You can have multiple disallows just like you tried. Have a look [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html).

Comment: @Cynthia Great! Also I read from **norfavrell** link that we could somehow hide files using Options -Indexes: _If you want to hide the included files you can disable directory indexes with the Options -Indexes directive on your .htaccess file, though._ Maybe do you know how to do that?

Comment: Edited my .htaccess code in my answer to include the -indexes directive. :)

Comment: I put `Order deny,allow Deny from all` .htaccess and get error on SSI include virtual. Does SSI really work with this rule? Maybe I have some problems.

Comment: Email me (it's in my profile) with the error message and an example of how you are calling your includes.